# Django how to filter nested relationships

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have these two models

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    subject_info = models.ForeignKey(SubjectInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='assignments')
    release_results = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_marks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
```

```
class StudentAssignment(models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='submissions')
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    scored = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In my view I am trying to get all assignments that either:

1) Don't have a studentassignment related to the user

2) Have a studentassignment related to the user but the submitted value is False

I did it like this:

```
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Assignment.objects.filter(
            subject_info__teacher__school=self.request.user.student.school,
            subject_info__related_class=self.request.user.student.current_class,
            subject_info__subject__in=self.request.user.student.subjects,
            deadline__gte=datetime.now(),
        ).exclude(
            submissions__isnull=True,
            submissions__student=self.request.user.student,
            submissions__submitted=False,
        )
        return queryset
```

But it is not returning correct values.

How can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this using [**`Q`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q

queryset = Assignment.objects.filter(
            Q(submissions__isnull=True) | Q(submissions__student__user=request.user, submissions__submitted=False)
        )
```

Comment: I don't think it would work because I said 'where the assignment doesn't contain a studentassignment that is related to the user making the request'

Comment: Try to take a look at the use-case but thanks for trying though

Comment: I do not think you have mentioned: **where the assignment doesn't contain a studentassignment that is related to the user making the request** anywhere in the question. Anyway, updated my answer.

Comment: It seems to be working now. Thank you for your time